# Sharing a common memory in python

Tags: python, c

Below is code with C implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union test
{
    int a;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    union test t1;
    int z = 0x0112;
    t1.a = z;
    return 0;
}
```

Here memory is shared between a and c
value of a is 0x112
value of c is 0x12

How should this be implemented in python
Current shown union is for example i need to this for an array of intger

In python below is values received in list.

```
value = m1.read_registers(0, 100, 3)
```

value is a LIST of 100

Now i want to extract each element and assign to a new variable

```
reg1 = value[0]
reg2 = value[1]
'
'
'
reg100 = value[3]
```

The above requires an iterative loop to update every time. Which consumes an amount of time.

Can this be directly done by sharing memory

```
value = [reg1 , reg2 , ......,reg100]
value = m1.read_registers(0, 100, 3)
print(reg1)
print(reg2)
'
'
```

Comment: Check out `ctypes` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: @oda I think the OP is asking about an alternative to `union` in Python, not how to interface Python with C.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why specifically in Python?

Comment: How is an array of integers a union; that is (in a way) a single datatype? You should then show the C equivalent, because the current example is between an integer and a byte.

Comment: I think OP means an array of `test` unions (the `test`  union type is effectively an integer).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve with this union and show some Python code where you would want to use this. Using a `union` to access data of one type as a different type is highly implementation specific. For example if you write the `int a` menber and then read the `char c` member it depends on endianness of your processor which byte of the `int` value you will get. On a big endian system, when you write the value `0x112` to `a`, the value of `c` will probably be `0`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes you are right how can it be done in python

Comment: @SF Creating variables in that way is a very bad idea. If you already have the integers in the list, you simply use the list. What difference does writing `value[j + 1]` have compared to writing `regj`? Internally what you are getting with a list  is a variable-length array of pointers to objects (in this case, Python integers).

Comment: I think the question is just generally about manipulating and interpreting raw data in Python in a low-level way.

Comment: As @oda suggested, the __real__ question is, why do you want to use `regj` instead of `value[j+1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying question, I think, is: "how do I cause a Python variable to refer to some subset of an existing sequence, such that changes are reflected?"

The answer depends on the type of the sequence you are using.

For immutable things like `str` or `bytes` the question is trivial; there are no changes to reflect in the first place.

For iterables that don't store all their data up front (such as an open file) you are realistically out of luck. Rework your algorithm so that you don't need this.

For `list` you are again out of luck.

For your own user-defined sequence types, you can define e.g. your `__getitem__` so that it returns some kind of proxy object. (If you are interested in this, please ask a more specific question.)

However, it appears that you are specifically concerned with manipulating a low-level buffer of mutable data, where the buffer is raw bytes and the "references" interpret that data in some way.

For this case, you can use `memoryview` to create views on an underlying mutable buffer (the simplest choice for the buffer is `bytearray`). The data "seen" by `memoryview` will automatically update when the underlying buffer is modified (it does not internally store a copy of data, but instead simply "knows" what part of the buffer it is examining). However, you will still have to do the interpretation whenever you examine one of the `memoryview` "references".

For example:

```py
test = bytearray(b'abcd')
# Let's start by making a view of the entire data.
a = memoryview(test)
# indexing `a` gives you an individual byte...
a[0] # == 97
# but slicing gives you another view object.
c = a[0:1]
# The representation of the `memoryview` doesn't show the underlying memory.
# We need to do some conversion.
int.from_bytes(a, 'big') # we have to specify endianness, too.
int.from_bytes(c, 'big') # but it works for any amount of bytes.
# We can change the raw data...
test[0] = 0
# and the change is reflected in the int conversion results.
int.from_bytes(a, 'big') # 6447972 rather than 1633837924
int.from_bytes(c, 'big') # 0 rather than 97
# We can also change data via the views.
c[0] = ord('x')
a[1] = ord('y')
test # is now bytearray(b'xycd')
```

Note that, while slicing a `memoryview` will give a new `memoryview` on the same buffer, we cannot get the same results by slicing beforehand - `c = memoryview(test[0:1])` would create a *new buffer* for the slice, and then make a view over that entire buffer.